# ADOMD.net x64 vs. x86 assembly?

Tags: assemblies, ssas, adomd.net

Does anyone know if the x64 and x86 installations of ADOMD.net contain different assemblies? I've installed both, and they both include what looks like the exact same assembly `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll`, one in [Program Files] the other in [Program Files (x86)]--same version number, exact same size, so I'm assuming the assembly was compiled for 'Any CPU' and can be used interchangeably on either platform.